# How to iterate over a JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, json

For instance, I have an array of these objects returned in a user_timeline from twitter. The object looks like this:

```
[{"created_at": "Fri Nov 02 23:44:11 +0000 2012", "id": 264513266083049472, "id_str": "264513266083049472", "text": "@JessLeighMusic do it! This time my dad will be playing!", "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e", "truncated": false, "in_reply_to_status_id": 264489640013217793, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "264489640013217793", "in_reply_to_user_id": 38814642, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "38814642", "in_reply_to_screen_name": "JessLeighMusic", "user": {
"id": 143161594,
"id_str": "143161594",
"name": "Mandala Faulkner",
"screen_name": "Mandalastar",
"location": "Ada, Ok",
"description": "I love to sing, play guitar, piano, and flute, but I am still learning everyday. I perform at the Quality Inn the first and third Friday of every month.",
"url": null,
"entities": {
    "description": {
        "urls": []
    }
},
```

And so on and so forth. Here's my question: when using a foreach in PHP, how to instruct the code to "drill down" to the elements in each {} set? I've never worked with JSON objects before and Twitter's API documentatin is dreadful.

Comment: Why do you need to use foreach? You can simple get an object using `json_decode` and then access the properties. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to print the text of a tweet from a larger object, like the one above; I just don't know exactly what kind of array the json_decode returns, so I don't know how to drill down to get the info from the sublevels that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
$list = json_decode($json_text, true);
foreach ($list as $item) {
    // $item is the each {} set you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode()` is your friend here. Turns proper json strings into nested php `array()`s.

You would then `foreach` over the resulting array:

```
$json = "json string here";
$result = json_decode($json);

foreach ($result as $object)
{
    //do stuff
}
```